# Cordova how to uninstall app before run

Tags: cordova

**Thank you for your time dear reader,**

im trying remove/uninstall the app from the device before rebuilding and running it.
 Else `cordova run android` would only kind of update the app and preserve its local storage etc.

Is that possible with any command?
Searched the online tutorials / manpages etc. without succes - and im kind of bamboozled because I thought that would be the most basic thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [adb uninstall](http://adbshell.com/commands/adb-uninstall) to remove an installed Android app by its package ID:

`$ adb uninstall com.my.app`

For convenience I have wrapped this in a shell script which extracts the package ID from an APK:

`adb_uninstall_by_apk.sh`:

`#!/bin/bash
    # Uninstalls app from device using the ID from an APK
    # Usage: adb_uninstall_by_apk.sh some.apk
    pkg=$(aapt dump badging "$1"|awk -F" " '/package/ {print $2}'|awk -F"'" '/name=/ {print $2}')
    adb uninstall $pkg`

I then wrapped it again specifically for Cordova debug builds:

`cordova_debug_uninstall.sh`:

`#!/bin/bash
    # Uninstalls app from device using the ID from a pre-built debug APK in a cordova-android@7+ project
    # Usage: cordova_debug_uninstall.sh
    adb_uninstall_by_apk.sh platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk`

I can then easily do a fresh install:

`$ cordova_debug_uninstall.sh && cordova run android`

Comment: Awesome!
Thank you so much.
Im kind of embarrassed that I didnt think about adb myself :)